# Disabling the trackpad from the command line

Tags: macos, command-line, macbook-pro, trackpad

How can I disable the trackpad (without restarting my computer) from the command-line on OS X Mavericks?

Comment: I really don't think there's a way you can do this.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the following Code

`sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBMultitouch.kext/`

Answer (score 2):

The following commands have the same effect as checking the "Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present" option in the Accessibility panel of System Preferences:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad USBMouseStopsTrackpad 1
$ defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad USBMouseStopsTrackpad 1
```

To re-enable the trackpad:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad USBMouseStopsTrackpad 0
$ defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad USBMouseStopsTrackpad 0
```

Comment: Doesn't work in mojave

Comment: Doesn't work in Ventura. The setting is set, but trackpad still works. Does it only work if an Apple Mouse is connected?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable your trackpad when an external mouse/trackpad is present:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3608

For whatever reason you'd wish to disable your trackpad, even if no other device is attached:
https://superuser.com/questions/606338/unix-terminal-how-to-disable-trackpad

Comment: The latter is my case. Unfortunately, it didn't work. The trackpad was not disabled.

Comment: Hopefully you didn't follow the ['slam you fist 3 times'](http://superuser.com/a/919951/432665) advice on this thread! J