# Turning the Magic trackpad off from the terminal

Tags: magic-trackpad

Is there a way to turn off the Apple Magic Trackpad from the terminal?

I am not looking for a way to pair the Magic Trackpad with a Mac computer.

Comment: Look at this:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125324/disabling-the-trackpad-from-the-command-line